# Cubism - event expression returns only timestamp values

Tags: cubism.js

I'm storing data in Cube. Here's a sample expression:
    `Some({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51ec6f8c44ae76018fac7efd"} , "t" : { "$date" : "2013-07-21T23:34:21.000Z"} , "d" : { "urlbase" : "egauge5315.egaug.es" ,"Total Usage" : 3812.0}})`

I started the Cube Evaluator and went over to this url: 
`http://localhost:1081/1.0/event?expression=curbdata.eq(urlbase,'egauge2962.egaug.es')` which gives me `{"time":"2013-07-21T23:34:21.000Z"}`.

What changes should I make in the expression so that I get the 'Total Usage' value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/square/cube/wiki/Queries#event-expressions if you want more than the time of the event, you need to specify the values you want returned. So in your example, I'm thinking something like this:

```
http://localhost:1081/1.0/event?expression=curbdata(Total Usage).eq(urlbase,'egauge2962.egaug.es')`
```

(although I'm not sure how it deals with spaces in value names; it may need to be quoted).